# Будут ли конфликтовать две формы?

Tags: php, forms

Доброго времени суток !

Есть 2 формы, одна отправляет, другая настраивает первую форму.

Вопрос: Будут ли формы конфликтовать, если у них будет один php обработчик, при условии того, что в обработчике стоит проверка с какой формы была нажата кнопка ?

Предварительный код обработчика:

```
if(isset($_POST['sendPostFormButton']))
{
    //Внутренности обработчика первой формы
}

if(isset($_POST['sendApplySettingsButton']))
{
    //Внутренности обработчика второй формы
}
```

Comment: как запрограммируете, так и будет

Comment: Вы не получите ответа на такой вопрос без примера кода.

Comment: Нужен код. Форма это просто пачка полей в $_POST/$_GET с точки зрения php, поэтому будет ли она конфликтовать с чем-то зависит от реализации клиентской и серверной части. Вам как нужно, чтобы конфликтовали или чтобы нет? )

Comment: @wirtwelt, чтобы не конфликтовали) Я дополнил вопрос кодом, при таком коде возможны конфликты ?

Comment: Нет, при таком коде конфликты невозможны.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, если вы в клиентской части разделите формы на две и не будете их перекрывать:

```
<form>
...
<input type="submit" name="sendPostFormButton" value="Отправить">
</form>

<form>
...
<input type="submit" name="sendApplySettingsButton" value="Настроить">
</form>
```

В этом случае все должно пройти отлично. Обратите внимание на атрибут `name` у кнопок, не забудьте про него, это важно )

Удачи

P.S. Есть еще классная штука в HTML, можно строить сложные имена у полей ввода, вроде

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="firstForm[field1]">
<input type="text" name="firstForm[field2]">
...
</form>

<form>
<input type="text" name="secondForm[field1]">
<input type="text" name="secondForm[field2]">
...
</form>
```

PHP для нас предоставит массив `$_POST['firstForm'] = array('field1' => <...>, 'field2' => <...>)` в первом случае и точно такое же, но с именем `$_POST['secondForm']` во втором случае. Это так, просто для общего развития, очень удобно при работе с кучей однотипных форм